# LINQ return a value IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, pipeline

Is it possible to return a linq query like below with a return type or is it readonly like a foreach statement?

Thanks!

```
var s = "sean oneill, 26/06/1985; matt sheridan, 22/09/1984; Jenny Hutching, 21/03/1972";

var s9 = ParseDateOfBirth(s);

private string ParseDateOfBirth(string info)
{
       return info.Split(';').Select(n => n.Split(',')).Select(n => new { name = n[0].Trim(), datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(n[1], "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply running it to find out?

Comment: What do you mean?  do you want what you wrote in query syntax or are you trying to return an IEnumerable from your method?  If the second you need to declare a type and just return `IEnumerable<YourClass>`.  If the first then

Answer (score 2):

Your linq expression returns an annonymous object at the end. So you cannot use string as the return type of your method.

You can use dynamic as the type

```
private dynamic ParseDateOfBirth(string info)
{
        return info.Split(';')
           .Select(n => n.Split(','))
           .Select(n => new { 
                     name = n[0].Trim(), 
                     datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(n[1].Trim(), 
                                                    "d/M/yyyy",
                                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
 }
```

Or even better, create a DTO to represent the data you are returning and use that

```
public class UserInfo
{
  public string Name { set; get; }
  public DateTime Datetime { set; get; }        
}

private IEnumerable<UserInfo> ParseDateOfBirth(string info)
{
   return info.Split(';').Select(n => n.Split(','))
              .Select(n => new UserInfo  { 
                          Name = n[0].Trim(), 
                          Datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(n[1].Trim(), 
                                             "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });

}
```

Now when you call this method with the input

```
var s = "sean oneill, 26/06/1985; matt sheridan, 22/09/1984; Jenny Hutching, 21/03/1972";

var result = ParseDateOfBirth(s);
```

the variable `result` will be a collection of 3 `UserInfo` objects.

Comment: You need to Trim the date string before paring it: `DateTime.ParseExact(n[1].Trim()`

Comment: @JamesCurran Good catch. ParseExact will fail if you do not do that. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Much appreciated.